# Как аккуратно перебрать и вывести 2 значения из массива?

Tags: php, парсер, api

Доброго времени суток, подскажите, пожалуйста:

```
print_r ($b['response']['wall'][0]['text']);
print_r ($b['response']['profiles'][0]['first_name']);
```

В массиве ['response'] два подмассива ['wall'] и ['profiles'],  в ['wall'] содержится текст ['text'] поста который разместил автор а в ['profiles'] содержится имя разместившего ['first_name'];

получается перебрать и достать только все посты

```
foreach($b['response']['wall'] as $value) :
$text = strip_tags ($value['text']);?>
<textarea rows="17" cols="47" name="text" ><? echo $text; ?></textarea>
<textarea rows="17" cols="47" name="autor" ><? echo $autor; ?></textarea>
<?endforeach;?>
```

Подскажите как синхронно с постами достать и имя автора в переменную $autor?

Comment: Рекомендую поменять структуру запроса на выборку данных. Один ряд результирующей выборки должен содержать все данные по конкретному посту. Похоже что проблема в структуре базы данных и изначально данные при сохранении распределяются хз как.

Comment: Работаю с  API Вконтакте, к сожалению не знаю как поменять структуру запроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные получены криво, соответственно решение такое же кривое. Но должно работать =) :

```
// предполагаем, что кол-во элементов 'wall' = кол-ву элементов 'profiles'
$count = count($b['response']['wall']);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { ?>

    <textarea rows="17" cols="47" name="text" ><?=$b['response']['wall'][$i]['text'];?></textarea>
    <textarea rows="17" cols="47" name="text" ><?=$b['response']['profiles'][$i]['first_name'];?></textarea>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Правильно понимаю, нужно использовать вместо цикла foreach ?

Comment: в данном случае да.

Comment: Удалил  foreach поставил ваш код пишет  "Страница не доступна"

Comment: вы его прям скопировали? обратите внимание на открывающие и закрывающие php теги. и у меня там опечатка в условии, сейчас поправил.

Comment: Да, все теги учел.

Comment: у меня в условии for была опечатка, я её исправил.

Comment: Спасибо, работает, но проблема как и у примера ниже, не правильно подставляет имена, со сдвигом.

Comment: Если сдвиг закономерен, то просто вычислите его и правьте номер элемента из массива ['profiles'] (['profiles'][$i + 1, как-то так).  Но я бы рекомендовал всё же подробнее изучить api. С такой структурой ответа токмо на костылях работать можно)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то примерно вот так:

```
  foreach($b['response'] as $item) {
    foreach ($item['wall'] as $post) {
      echo $text;
      echo $item['profiles'][0]['first_name'];
    }
  }
```

Если же у каждого поста могут быть разные автора, то нужно собирать новый массив в цикле и потом выводить опять таки в цикле

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, количество элементов в подмассивах wall и profiles одинаково. То есть, одному посту соответствует один автор.

Следовательно, цикл превращается в это:

```
foreach($b['response']['wall'] as $key => $value) : // добавим $key
$text = strip_tags ($value['text']);;
$author = $b['response']['profiles'][$key]['first_name']; // автор с тем же $key   
endforeach;
```